# vscode.dev: can't connect to remote tunnel

Tags: vscode-remote

Anybody else getting the following error all of a sudden?

```
An unexpected error occurred that requires a reload of this page.
The workbench failed to connect to the server (Error: No remote extension installed to resolve tunnel.)
```

Everything was working fine just a day ago.

The remote is a desktop with a normal VS Code install. Been connecting to it without problems for weeks. No new extensions or anything like that. No recent updates either. I guess I'm just looking for other people experiencing the same thing. Could this be an issue with vscode.dev?

Answer (score 0):

Our team faced the problem today.

While it was working like a charm previously over any browser, it suddenly stopped with that error.

Using the extension [Remote - Tunnels](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.remote-server) locally to connect the remote session solved it.

PS: but we still don't know the issue root cause.

Answer (score -1):

It started working again after about 24 hours. I did nothing.

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).